Getting error while installing unlocked pacakge
Hi I am trying to learn SFP.
I am following steps defined in: https://docs.flxbl.io/sfp/configuring-a-project/setup-salesforce-org#id-2.-install-sfpowerscripts-artifact-unlocked-package
I have enabled Dev Hub and Enabled Unlocked Packages and Second-Generation Managed Packages
Now when I try to run command like this:
sf package install --package 04t1P000000ka9mQAA -o MyDeveloperOrg --security-type=AdminsOnly --wait=120

Get error like below:
D:\Project\MyDeveloperOrg\MyDeveloperOrg> sf package install --package 04t1P000000ka9mQAA -o MyDeveloperOrg --security-type=AdminsOnly --wait=120
Waiting 120 minutes for package install to complete.... done
Error (1): Encountered errors installing the package! Installation errors:
1) Apex compile failure, Details: Apex class PackageTests: line 67, column 28: Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void afterUpdate() from the type Product2Helper
2) Apex compile failure, Details: Apex class PackageTests: line 78, column 37: Constructor not defined: [Product2Extension].<Constructor>()
3) Apex compile failure, Details: Apex class PackageTests: line 92, column 41: Constructor not defined: [AnnouncementQueueable].<Constructor>()

When I check I found that all above 3 errors are valid.
Here is the code of the classes:
Have someone any idea how we can resolve the same?

Can you please share code for the classes which shows error ?

Updated question with class codes.

I created scratch org and installed the package.
It got installed successfully.
When I debugged the dev org again and found that the issue was with the test class already existing in the org.
Removed the test class and ran the installation command again.
Able to resolve the issue.


Apex compile failure, Details: Apex class PackageTests: line 67, column 28: Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void afterUpdate() from the type Product2Helper

For above error , I see that Order list is passed whereas Product2Helper is expecting List of Product2 records as per below signature -
public static void AfterUpdate(List<Product2> prodList, List<Product2> prodOldList){


Apex compile failure, Details: Apex class PackageTests: line 78, column 37: Constructor not defined: [Product2Extension].()

For this error you need to define below constructor in Product2Extension:
public Product2Extension(){}

or you can use this answer for testing with controller extensions.

Apex compile failure, Details: Apex class PackageTests: line 92, column 41: Constructor not defined: [AnnouncementQueueable].()

This error is similar to above, you can either define a constructor for AnnouncementQueueable like below or modify the test class to use the existing constructor.
public AnnouncementQueueable() {}

Above solutions can fix the errors in question.
This issue is seen in unlocked packages since it allows to skip validation while uploading of packages. I would recommend to compile all apex classes in Devhub org before creating a package version.

I have created a scratch org and tried to install the package and It is installed successfully(This is strange). But I am not able to see any classes there.

ok , can you please confirm if classes are in the same directory as specified in the command like? sf package create -t Unlocked -r force-app/main/default/MyPackage5 -n MyPackage5 --org-dependent

Please refer these steps for package creation.

This was due to the existing class having issue in the org.
I removed the test class and package installed successfully.

ok, but the errors would still need fixes. OR maybe the existing test class is different from the one you shared.

The test class is not part of this package. So I removed that class.

This is new info. No problem.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
